# Simulate MMC card in Linux kernel

Tags: kernel-module, device-driver

I try to add mmc_spi module to my 2.6.21 kernel to communicate with mmc card via SPI.
I suppose that 3 modules are neccessary:
mmc_core
mmc_block
mmc_spi

My mmc_blk device is registered in system (cat /proc/devices). 
I've created proper /dev/mmc. Major is correct.
But when I try to mount it - I get error - no such device or address.

I suppose that one of the structure has to be filled, to tell linux that the card is inside the socked. I have to do it by hand now.
How can I simulate it ?

Comment: I see that I need to call .probe from mmc_spi module. But I'm not sure who can do it (with 'spi_device *spi' argument).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to have a platform device that will reference the new mmc_spi module.  You can normally create a kernel module for this, but in many architectures with 'static' MMC support this will be in the appropriate 'arch/foo/platform' directories.

If you are working on a system with open-firmware (device-tree, dts, dtb etc.) support then you simply have to add "mmc_spi" to the compatible flag for the SPI slave entry into your DTS.